# Https-Request processed twice

Tags: asp.net-core, react-hooks, antd, iis-10

i hope that someone can help me.
Occasionally i am facing the following behaviour in my Webapplication (ASP.NETCORE 6, IIS 10, React, Ant-Design).
A Https-Request fired with Jquery-Ajax is processed twice in my App.
First i thougt i have an Issue in my Client-Side Code, so i implemented a logging to find out what the user is doing.
But the Function btnBelegSpeichernClicked where the Ajax is called is only fired one time in the App (according to the console.log, where i log every call of the function btnBelegSpeichernClicked) but in the IIS-Log and also in the Database, the call is successfully  processed twice.

Maybe someone has a hint for us, where we further should investigate. I am going to implement something to avoid this behavior but that feels much like an workaround i am curious what is causing that behaviour and what i am doing wrong.

```
const btnBelegSpeichernClicked = (values: any) => {

        LoggingApp(BuildInfoStringForLoggingApp("btnBelegSpeichernClicked"), false);

            if (BelegSpeichernRunningGlobal) {
                return;
            }

            BelegSpeichernRunningGlobal = true;

            let belegForSpeichern: BelegSpeichern = new BelegSpeichern();
            belegForSpeichern.beleg = new Beleg();
            belegForSpeichern.beleg.text = values.belegtext;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "api/Beleg/Speichern",
                    data: JSON.stringify(belegForSpeichern),
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    global: true,
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done
                    (function (ajaxResultBeleg: BelegSpeichernResult, status, req) {
                   BelegSpeichernRunningGlobal = false;
                }).fail(function (jqxhr: JQueryXHR, textStatus: JQuery.Ajax.ErrorTextStatus, errorThrown: string) {
BelegSpeichernRunningGlobal = false;
});

}
```

Here is the Backend Controller. PS: The KeschKassaRunning.cs is a ConcurrentDictionary where i Store the ID of the Point of Sale because it is not allowed, to perform two request simultaneously at the same Point of Sale:

```
[Route("Speichern")]
        [HttpPost]
        public BelegSpeichernResultDTO BelegSpeichern([FromBody] BelegSpeichernDTO inPara)
        {

            string loggedInUser = Utils.GetLanuser(this.HttpContext);

            try
            {
               BelegSpeichernResultDTO returnDTO = new BelegSpeichernResultDTO();

                try
                {
                    string checkRun = KeschKassaRunning.CheckRunning(inPara.beleg.id_kassa);
                    if (checkRun != null)
                    {
                        returnDTO.error_liste.Add(checkRun);
                        return returnDTO;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        KeschKassaRunning.runningIdKassaList.TryAdd(inPara.beleg.id_kassa, DateTime.Now);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Core.Utils.WriteLoggingApp(ex, loggedInUser);
                    returnDTO.error_liste.Add("Aktion fehlgeschlagen. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.");
                    return returnDTO;
                }

                using (dbmodel db = new dbmodel())
                {
                    BelegErfassenBS bs = new();
                    BelegSpeichernResultBO bsResult = bs.Journalerfassung(UtilsDtoBuilder.MapSpeichernDTOtoSpeichernBO(inPara),
                                                                                      loggedInUser,
                                                                                      HttpContext,
                                                                                      db,
                                                                                      true);

                    returnDTO.warning_liste = bsResult.warning_liste;
                    returnDTO.error_liste = bsResult.error_liste;
                    if (bsResult.beleg_for_print_liste != null)
                    {
                        returnDTO.beleg_for_print_liste = new List<BelegDTO>();
                        foreach (BelegBO item in bsResult.beleg_for_print_liste)
                        {
                            returnDTO.beleg_for_print_liste.Add(BuildBelegForPrintDTO(item));
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        if (bsResult.error_liste != null &&
                            bsResult.error_liste.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Core.Utils.WriteLoggingAppToDatabase(BuildLoggingString(bsResult), loggedInUser);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Core.Utils.WriteLoggingApp(ex, loggedInUser);
                    }

                }

                try
                {
                    KeschKassaRunning.RemoveRunningKassa(inPara.beleg.id_kassa);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Core.Utils.WriteLoggingApp(ex, loggedInUser);
                }

                return returnDTO;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Core.Utils.WriteLoggingApp(ex, loggedInUser);
                KeschKassaRunning.RemoveRunningKassa(inPara.beleg.id_kassa);
                throw;
            }
```

Here is the IIS-Log (from Graylog) to the Call from that IP-Address of the specific Client (10.133.29.108):

2023-03-21 09:56:36.175 xxx.xxx.xxx.gv.at
2023-03-21 08:56:22 10.153.87.9 POST /xxx/api/Beleg/Speichern - 8443 - 10.153.121.50 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/111.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.topsecret/xxx 200 0 0 9640 3022 29119 095548$88biv@8029p70 10.133.29.10

2023-03-21 09:56:12.144 xxx.xxx.xxx.gv.at
2023-03-21 08:55:52 10.153.87.9 POST /xxx/api/Beleg/Speichern - 8443 - 10.153.121.51 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/111.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://www.topsecret/xxx 200 0 0 9640 3020 15766 095536$rwpg@8029p71 10.133.29.10

That happens maybe one or two Times per Month and we are unable to reproduce the issue in the Test-System.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you know this is not intentionally?

Comment: you might just implement something to prevent double-submits from the front-end...  another thing that can sometimes cause this is using the standard layout in ASP.NET.  It'll have a "@renderbody" directive that can cause double-posts-gets....

Comment: I Updated the Javascript/Typescript section. I dont wanted to post too much garbage but i deleted to much. I implemented a validation, to prevent that the function is called twice (BelegSpeichernRunningGlobal). Also i write every time, when the User starts the Function to the console.log (LoggingApp(BuildInfoStringForLoggingApp("btnBelegSpeichernClicked"), false);). Luckily the User hasnt refreshed the Browser so i got the entire log and the function was only called once at the specific time. there are many minutes between other calls. But at the Server the Request was processed twice.

Comment: it's going to be very hard to get to the bottom of it without being able to reproduce the error, though.  You should manually test until you find a repeatable procedure.

Comment: @pcalkins: thank you for the hint to "@renderbody". i am going to check this. yes, that is really hard. we are going to try it with automatic tests with tosca to reproduce it somehow and also manually. for now, i am going to implement a validation for every request. i generate a transaction-id in the client and i will store it to the database where this column is unique. but i am so curious, what the issue is :-)

Comment: what it makes much harder is the fact, that i am facing this error not very often. every day they store circa 2000 receipts and that happens only 1 or 2 times per month.

Comment: seemingly random bugs usually suggest timing issue or memory leak.  (I'd suspect timing issue involving whatever prevents the double-submit.)  I usually disable all GUI controls (a simple overlay) before sending the request but it'll depend on how your event handlers are written.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions :-). i am going to check the timing and implement further validation to prevent that behavior.